# Drush says it needs Composer, but Composer is already installed?

Tags: 7, drush

I've recently re-provisioned my development box, and went to run a drush command but was met with

> Unable to load autoload.php. Drush now requires Composer in order to install its dependencies and autoload classes. Please see README.md

I then tested to see if Composer was installed and found it was (version 1.0.3).

Would anyone know what I can do here?

Comment: How did you test to see if composer was installed? Drush doesn't think it is so maybe it's not in your path

Comment: I just typed `composer` and it spat out the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Drupal core isssue about this: [Catch error(s) from composer install not being run and return friendly error](https://www.drupal.org/node/2691003).

**tl;dr**

Basically, you need to run `composer install` from inside your docroot.